# Problems checking existence of directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to load configurations from an external file (config.txt). The file contains info about directories on my drive. I have written a method for reading one line of the config.txt and return its value. A second method checks the existence of a directory. The first call of latter method  always results into a *False*, even if given directory exists.

I tried different directories, even the same directory in both lines. For the first call I always get a "False". The second call results into the right answer.
If the method is called from the terminal with any directory I get the right result.

```
import os    

def _load_config(setting_line, setting_print):
     temp_file = open("config.txt", "r")
     temp_setting = temp_file.readlines()[setting_line]
     temp_file.close()
     print(setting_print,temp_setting)
     return temp_setting

 def _Check_Folder_Exists(temp_path):
    if os.path.exists(temp_path):
        print("dir found")
    else:
        print("dir NOT found")

dir_A = _load_config(0, "dir A:")
_Check_Folder_Exists(dir_A)

dir_B = _load_config(1, "dir B:")
_Check_Folder_Exists(dir_B)
```

the config.txt looks like:

```
C:\A
C:\B
```

Both directories exist and are accessible.

Results are always:

```
dir A: C:\A

dir NOT found
dir B: C:\B
dir found
```

Also: I can't see why there is an empty line after the first one.

Comment: `temp_setting = temp_file.readlines()[setting_line].rstrip('\n')`

Comment: Can see why I wasn't aware of the \n when it was so obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two issues are related. It's because when you use `readlines()`, you get the whole line including the line break; so the value of `dir_A` is actually `C:\A\n`.

Use `strip`:

```
temp_setting = temp_file.readlines()[setting_line].strip()
```

Comment: What if the path ends with a space, though? You'll end up stripping that, as well.

Comment: Can see why I wasn't aware of the \n when it was so obvious. Thank you!